Conditions in aggregate functions
I was solving some SQL tasks and got confused with the following thing:
CREATE TABLE data (
  len INT
);

INSERT INTO data (len)
VALUES 
  (NULL),
  (100), 
  (200),
  (300),
  (400);

suppose we've created such a table and we wanna count all values that are less than 200. I am using this online compiler to do it.
my first attempt gives 1 as expected
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE len < 200)
FROM data

then I thought whether I can simplify it and just do
SELECT COUNT(len < 200) FROM data

but it gives 4 as an answer.
So my question is: can we use logic expressions inside of aggregate functions? If the answer is NO, why?

Hi - why don't you just use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE len < 200"? You seem to be overcomplicating what should be a very simple query

Try SELECT COUNT(case when len < 200 then 1 else null end) FROM data Output is 1. Count(value) - counts not null values. Value (len<200) is true or false, not null.

@ValNik, it does not look neat, I think we should avoid if-else constructions as much as we can = ). Actually the question arose because I've tried to write your code as SELECT count(len < 200) and it does not work and I'm just trying to understand why (what's going on with SELECT COUNT(len < 200)

@NickW, yep, you are right. I'm just trying to understand the mistake I've came across. If it was a job task I'd just write WHERE like you offered

COUNT function will count non-null entries. Your len < 200 condition returns non-null boolean results for almost every entry in data. ie. Both TRUE and FALSE values are contributing to result count. The only entry not counted is the NULL value in table, because NULL < 200 returns NULL.

You can use logic expression in aggregate function. You should know, how aggregate function works. I'm about count() function. And expression (len<200) is true or false, not null. Count() counts not null values.  And you can avoid if-else constructin, if you want;)

@ValNik, ELSE NULL in a CASE expression is redundant. One could also achieve the desired result with COUNT(NULLIF(len < 200, FALSE)). The choice between functionally equivalent code should be driven by readability; i.e., which construct most clearly conveys intent and minimizes cognitive load.

See example without if-else SELECT sum(cast(len<200 as int)) FROM data Or SELECT sum((len<200)::int) FROM data

@JohnH, yes, you are right, ELSE  null is redundant (default). I wanted to highlight exactly count(null).

COUNT(expression) computes the number of rows for which expression is not NULL. COUNT(*) computes the total number of rows because * is the row value, which is never NULL for any row, even if every column in a row is NULL. The < operator can return one of three results: TRUE, FALSE, or NULL. Keep in mind that NULL is not a value, it is a state. The expression COUNT(len < 200) only returns NULL when len is NULL; therefore, any valued len will contribute to the count. COUNT(NULL) will always return 0 regardless of the number of rows.

count(*) counts all input rows regardless of their contents. Period. That's according to the SQL standard, and does not depend on the meaning of the symbol * in other contexts.
Postgres has a separate (faster) implementation for count(*). The manual:

count ( * ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows.
count ( "any" ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows in which the input value is not
null.

The definition of the variant count("any") also answers why your 2nd query counts all rows with not-null len.
To actually simplify your query - and make it faster, or dramatically faster for big tables and selective criteria matching an index:
SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE len < 200;

See:

For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?

